# Connection to MySQL with JSP using Eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jsp, jdbc

I am a newbie and I wanted to know how build path and all `mysql.jar` to Eclipse so that I can use it for JSP and I have already made a dynamic web project configured with Tomcat. Only the database connection is not happening.

The error is:

```
java.sql.SQLException : No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/pj_company
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `lib` folder your `WEB-INF` folder and paste the [mysql driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html) jar in it, and then in eclipse, right click on the jar file --> Build Path --> Add to Build Path